# x2go terminates session immediately to xfce x2go server

Tags: x2go

I have troubles getting x2go up and running. My setup is

- Server: Debian 9
- Client: Debian 8

When I try to connect to the server, the session is terminated immediately.

Log of the server (`/var/log/syslog`):

```
Sep  4 11:03:31 rocket /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go agent session with ID guenther-50-1504515810_stDXFCE_dp24
Sep  4 11:03:32 rocket /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: Setting X keyboard according to /home/guenther/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504515810_stDXFCE_dp24/keyboard
Sep  4 11:03:32 rocket /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="xfce4-session"
Sep  4 11:03:54 rocket /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[614]: guenther-50-1504515810_stDXFCE_dp24: found stale X-server process (8719), sending SIGKILL
Sep  4 11:07:03 rocket /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go agent session with ID guenther-50-1504516022_stDXFCE_dp24
Sep  4 11:07:04 rocket /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: Setting X keyboard according to /home/guenther/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516022_stDXFCE_dp24/keyboard
Sep  4 11:07:04 rocket /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="xfce4-session"
Sep  4 11:07:26 rocket /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[614]: guenther-50-1504516022_stDXFCE_dp24: found stale X-server process (10334), sending SIGKILL
Sep  4 11:08:05 rocket /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go agent session with ID guenther-50-1504516084_stDXFCE_dp24
Sep  4 11:08:06 rocket /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: Setting X keyboard according to /home/guenther/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516084_stDXFCE_dp24/keyboard
Sep  4 11:08:06 rocket /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="xfce4-session"
Sep  4 11:08:28 rocket /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go agent session with ID guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24
Sep  4 11:08:28 rocket /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: Setting X keyboard according to /home/guenther/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24/keyboard
Sep  4 11:08:28 rocket /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="xfce4-session"
Sep  4 11:08:28 rocket /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[614]: guenther-50-1504516084_stDXFCE_dp24: found stale X-server process (11298), sending SIGKILL
Sep  4 11:08:28 rocket /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[614]: guenther-50-1504516084_stDXFCE_dp24, pid 11298: cleaning up stale X11 socket file: /tmp/.X11-unix/X50
Sep  4 11:08:28 rocket /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[614]: guenther-50-1504516084_stDXFCE_dp24, pid 11298: cleaning up stale X11 lock file: /tmp/.X50-lock
Sep  4 11:08:51 rocket /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[614]: guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24: found stale X-server process (12063), sending SIGKILL
```

Client Log (output of `x2goclient --debug`)

```
x2go-INFO-1> "Starting X2Go Client..."
x2go-WARNING-1> "Non-fatal: can't load translator: :/i18n/x2goclient_c"
x2go-WARNING-1> "Trying to load language with lower preference, if existent."
x2go-WARNING-1> "Non-fatal: can't load translator: :/i18n/qt_c"
x2go-WARNING-1> "Trying to load language with lower preference, if existent."
x2go-INFO-3> "Started X2Go Client."
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:518> "$HOME=/home/grg"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2279> Reading 1 sessions from config file.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sessionbutton.cpp:341> Creating QPixmap with session icon: ":/img/icons/128x128/x2gosession.png".
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2759> Creating QPixmap with session icon: '":/img/icons/128x128/x2gosession.png"'.
WARNING: failed to kill process group '29643': No such process
x2go-INFO-8> "Starting connection to server: 10.70.1.5:22"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2860> Starting new ssh connection to server:"10.70.1.5":"22" krbLogin: false
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:175> SshMasterConnection, host "10.70.1.5"port 22user "guenther"useproxy falseproxyserver ""proxyport 22
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:212> Starting SSH connection without Kerberos authentication.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:216> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x22daa70)  created. 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:452> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x22daa70)  entering thread. 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:488> libssh not initialized yet. Initializing.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:799> cserverAuth
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:814> state: 1

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:996> Challenge authentication failed. Trying password mechanism if available.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1002> Password mechanism available. Continuing.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1006> Password authentication requested.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:664> User authentication OK.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2957> SSH connection established.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3266> Continue normal X2Go session
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 0: "export HOSTNAME && x2golistsessions"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:204> this=SshProcess(0x22db8b0)  Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, ' "4a2c74f2-ad71-4c70-8319-da221aa2f8e1" ', ' "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:4a2c74f2-ad71-4c70-8319-da221aa2f8e1"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; export HOSTNAME && x2golistsessions; echo "X2GODATAEND:4a2c74f2-a" '); 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1325> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1327> Passing new channel conenction object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1329> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1517> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1521> New channel:0x7f3b94010df0

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1552> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:4a2c74f2-ad71-4c70-8319-da221aa2f8e1"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; export HOSTNAME && x2golistsessions; echo "X2GODATAEND:4a2c74f2-ad71-4c70-8319-da221aa2f8e1";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1575> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1679> EOF on channel 0x7f3b94010df0; SshProcess object: 0
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1747> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1751> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:517> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "X2GODATABEGIN:4a2c74f2-ad71-4c70-8319-da221aa2f8e1
X2GODATAEND:4a2c74f2-ad71-4c70-8319-da221aa2f8e1
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:528> SSH finished: true - "" (0).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3655> ""
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:4206> Executing remote command: "X2GODPI=96 x2gostartagent 800x600 lan 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_24 us auto 1 D XFCE both"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 1: "X2GODPI=96 x2gostartagent 800x600 lan 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_24 us auto 1 D XFCE both"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:204> this=SshProcess(0x2270c70)  Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, ' "e46343d0-0e7a-4d14-a3c2-e45a90021485" ', ' "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:e46343d0-0e7a-4d14-a3c2-e45a90021485"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; X2GODPI=96 x2gostartagent 800x600 lan 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_2" '); 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1325> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1327> Passing new channel conenction object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1329> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1517> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1521> New channel:0x7f3b94010df0

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1552> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:e46343d0-0e7a-4d14-a3c2-e45a90021485"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; X2GODPI=96 x2gostartagent 800x600 lan 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_24 us auto 1 D XFCE both; echo "X2GODATAEND:e46343d0-0e7a-4d14-a3c2-e45a90021485";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1575> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1679> EOF on channel 0x7f3b94010df0; SshProcess object: 1
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1747> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1751> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:517> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "X2GODATABEGIN:e46343d0-0e7a-4d14-a3c2-e45a90021485
50
1e60d46f2996ef3ea8494e04191f44fa
12063
guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24
56245
56246
56247
X2GODATAEND:e46343d0-0e7a-4d14-a3c2-e45a90021485
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:528> SSH finished: true - "50
1e60d46f2996ef3ea8494e04191f44fa
12063
guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24
56245
56246
56247
" (1).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:5019> Agent output: "50
1e60d46f2996ef3ea8494e04191f44fa
12063
guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24
56245
56246
56247
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:372> Starting tunnel via SshProcess object 2: "localhost":56245 -> "localhost":57245

x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:5612> "Starting NX proxy, command: nxproxy -S nx/nx,options=/home/grg/.x2go/S-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24/options:50"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:157> Direct tunnel: waiting for connections on "localhost":57245
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: "
NXPROXY - Version 3.5.0

Copyright (C) 2001, 2010 NoMachine.
See http://www.nomachine.com/ for more information.

Info: Proxy running in client mode with pid '29704'.
Session: Starting session at 'Mon Sep  4 11:08:28 2017'.
Info: Using abstract X11 socket in kernel namespace for accessing DISPLAY=:0.
Info: Connecting to remote host 'localhost:57245'.
Info: Connection to remote proxy 'localhost:57245' established.
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:109> New TCP connection.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:114> New socket: 15
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1517> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1521> New channel:0x7f3b94010df0

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1527> Forwarding new channel, local port: 35382

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1545> New channel forwarded.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: "Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.
Warning: Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_24'. Assuming agent session.
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: "Info: Using LAN link parameters 1536/24/1/0.
Info: Using pack method '16m-jpeg-9' with session 'unix-kde-depth_24'.
Info: Not using NX delta compression.
Info: Not using ZLIB data compression.
Info: Not using ZLIB stream compression.
Info: Not using a persistent cache.
Info: Forwarding X11 connections to display ':0"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: "'.
Session: Session started at 'Mon Sep  4 11:08:28 2017'.
Info: Established X server connection.
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 3: "export PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG="${HOME}/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24/.pulse-client.conf";setsid x2goruncommand 50 12063 guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24 56246 xfce4-session nosnd D 1> /dev/null 2>/dev/null & exit"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:204> this=SshProcess(0x22feb70)  Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, ' "8ef330f4-655f-4424-829e-321249b4bc09" ', ' "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:8ef330f4-655f-4424-829e-321249b4bc09"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; export PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG="${HOME}/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516107" '); 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1325> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1327> Passing new channel conenction object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1329> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1517> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1521> New channel:0x7f3b94010e60

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1552> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:8ef330f4-655f-4424-829e-321249b4bc09"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; export PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG="${HOME}/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24/.pulse-client.conf";setsid x2goruncommand 50 12063 guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24 56246 xfce4-session nosnd D 1> /dev/null 2>/dev/null & exit; echo "X2GODATAEND:8ef330f4-655f-4424-829e-321249b4bc09";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1575> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: "Info: Using shared memory parameters 0/0K.
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1624> EOF on channel 0x7f3b94010e60; SshProcess object: 3
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1747> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1751> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:517> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "X2GODATABEGIN:8ef330f4-655f-4424-829e-321249b4bc09
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:528> SSH finished: true - "" (3).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:10970> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:12575> "Searching window with title: X2GO-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:10976> "Proxy window found: 50331903"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11016> Starting Xinerama timer.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:10905> "New proxy geometry: (x: 1, y: 39, w: 800, h: 600"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 4: "export DISPLAY=:50 ;printf %b '\''0 0 800 600'\'' >  $HOME/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24/xinerama.conf"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:204> this=SshProcess(0x2303b20)  Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, ' "57237104-bfbf-4438-a9c5-4334b5bc55ea" ', ' "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:57237104-bfbf-4438-a9c5-4334b5bc55ea"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; export DISPLAY=:50 ;printf %b '\''0 0 800 600'\'' >  $HOME/.x2go/" '); 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1325> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1327> Passing new channel conenction object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1329> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1517> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1521> New channel:0x7f3b94012000

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1552> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:57237104-bfbf-4438-a9c5-4334b5bc55ea"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; export DISPLAY=:50 ;printf %b '\''0 0 800 600'\'' >  $HOME/.x2go/C-guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24/xinerama.conf; echo "X2GODATAEND:57237104-bfbf-4438-a9c5-4334b5bc55ea";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1575> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1624> EOF on channel 0x7f3b94012000; SshProcess object: 4
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1747> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1751> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:517> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "X2GODATABEGIN:57237104-bfbf-4438-a9c5-4334b5bc55ea
X2GODATAEND:57237104-bfbf-4438-a9c5-4334b5bc55ea
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:528> SSH finished: true - "" (4).
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 14 (X_GetGeometry)
  Resource id:  0x30000ff
x2go-WARNING-7> "Error getting window geometry. (Did you close the window?)"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: "Session: Terminating session at 'Mon Sep  4 11:08:30 2017'.
Session"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1728> Socket 15 closed.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1747> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1751> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6071> Proxy wrote on stderr: ": Session terminated at 'Mon Sep  4 11:08:30 2017'.
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:5928> Deleting Proxy.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:5977> Waiting for proxy to exit.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:5997> Checking exit status.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 5: "x2gocmdexitmessage guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:204> this=SshProcess(0x2316e30)  Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, ' "ec374359-bfd9-49ad-8335-ec23bbf713e5" ', ' "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:ec374359-bfd9-49ad-8335-ec23bbf713e5"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; x2gocmdexitmessage guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24; echo "X2G" '); 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1325> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1327> Passing new channel conenction object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1329> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6054> Finished proxy.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1517> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1521> New channel:0x7f3b94010df0

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1552> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo "X2GODATABEGIN:ec374359-bfd9-49ad-8335-ec23bbf713e5"; export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"; export TERM="dumb"; x2gocmdexitmessage guenther-50-1504516107_stDXFCE_dp24; echo "X2GODATAEND:ec374359-bfd9-49ad-8335-ec23bbf713e5";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1575> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1624> EOF on channel 0x7f3b94010df0; SshProcess object: 5
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1747> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1751> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:517> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "X2GODATABEGIN:ec374359-bfd9-49ad-8335-ec23bbf713e5
exec xfce4-session
Loading profile from /etc/profile
Loading profile from /home/guenther/.profile
X2GODATAEND:ec374359-bfd9-49ad-8335-ec23bbf713e5
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:528> SSH finished: true - "exec xfce4-session
Loading profile from /etc/profile
Loading profile from /home/guenther/.profile
" (5).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:9366> "Command message: exec xfce4-session
Loading profile from /etc/profile
Loading profile from /home/guenther/.profile
"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:718> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x22daa70)  waiting for thread to finish. 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1436> Disconnecting ...

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1447> Deleting channel connections.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1455> Disconnecting session.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1461> Deleting sockets.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1468> All channels closed and session disconnected. Quiting session loop.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:722> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x22daa70)  thread finished. 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:729> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x22daa70)  finished destructor. 
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2759> Creating QPixmap with session icon: '":/img/icons/128x128/x2gosession.png"'.
```

I looked up the internet for half a day but without success. Help here is appreciated.

Comment: This is a problem with the DBUS. I found the solution here [1] with a small modification. 
### on X2Go Server
root@f24# cat >> /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session-test << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/xfce4-session > /dev/null
EOF
root@f24# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session-test
Start the x2go-session with xfce4-session-test command and it should work
[1] : https://bugs.x2go.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1083

Comment: I hope this will help anyone. I can't test it, because I switched back to gnome3...